# Pending execution

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

From this morning, one of our main SSIS jobs started to always return fail when executed. When we check in the log, it seems that all execution of the job stacked with the status "Pending execution."

We are using this SQL Server version:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3128.0 (X64) 
Dec 28 2012 20:23:12 
Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)
```

We have tried several things and are now out of ideas.

We've read the connect: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/629684/ssis-denali-need-a-way-to-recover-perpetually-pending-executions.

We restarted the MSSQL server and we still getting the same issue.

Has anyone experienced this behavior before? If yes, how did you solve it?

Thank you,
Sebastien

Comment: This link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7bb2615f-0438-45d5-8f75-4608048896d4/ssis-packages-go-into-pending-execution-state-after-sp1-cu7-deployment?forum=sqlintegrationservices seems to have a similar problem after installing 2012 SP1 CU7. Would that apply in your case? Their problem seems to have been resolved by fixing a .Net framework issue.

Comment: MS Framework 4.5.1 was installed, I removed it then I reinstall MS Framework 4.0 then applied updates. Still same result.

Comment: Right now, we are able to run the pack in ms visual studio as an alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We open a case with Microsoft. The solution was a security issue probably related to a GPO on the network.

We reassign the user rights of:

```
- Act as part of the operating system
- Adjust memory quotas for a process 
- Bypass traverse checking 
- Log on as batch job
- Log on as a service 
- Replace a process-level token
```

Everything run perfectly now.

Thanks!

Comment: Which user? The SQL Agent service account?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem here, turns out my user got his permissions removed by the infrastructure guys.

it's all about permissions.